# R programming - reading "#VALUE!" cells from csv generated by Excel

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file containing some cells with `#VALUE!` by `read.table()` function.

But, I am getting errors in the rows containing these cells. I tried to do it with `defining na.string=C("#VALUE!", "EMPTY","NA")`, but it didn't work.

Comment: By default, `#` is a comment character. You can change that by using `read.table(..., comment.char = "")`.

Comment: Further more, it's `na.strings = c(...)` and not `na.string = C(...)`, although R will recognize na.string, too.